# Installing node on a node.js project

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/node within my project, however i'm getting an error. It's looking for an npm package called `node-linux-arm` but that doesn't exist. It seems whatever check is used to get the OS version is returning `arm` only and not the specific version like `armv7l`. Even trying to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linux-armv7l (just to test), i would get an error saying `arm` is an unsupported platform.

Has anyone succesfully installed node on a node.js project in a raspberry pi?

Comment: If you're using Raspbian you want armv6 (aka `armhf`), which I doubt is a common node port -- if there's one, it will be specifically for the Pi.  If you aren't fussy about the version, though, 10.21 is ready-made in the Raspbian/RpiOS repo: `apt install nodejs`

Comment: @goldilocks i'm not trying to install node on raspbian, i've already done that. I have a node project in raspbian that i want to install the node module to as a dependency.